# Romantic restaurants in ski area in Austria

Tags: online-resources, austria, restaurants, recommendations

I'm looking for a romantic restaurant (fireplace, view of the snowy mountains, not too big) in Austria within ski region. The region should be reachable in about 2.5 h from Munich by car. How can I find one?

I would be happy with some special recommendations but also with a link to a website where I can search for one.

Comment: Austria has a lot of ski resorts. Can you bit a little bit more specific on the region? Or do you really want to cover whole Austria?

Comment: little bit too broad at present (see [faq]) - Austria has a lot of mountains, and ski regions, and restaurants ;)  Could you narrow it please - do you want near Vienna, or Salzburg perhaps? Where are you flying into?

Comment: @both comments: I've updated my question :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're willing to drive 2.5 hours from Munich you can reach some of the famous ski resorts in Austria. A good starting point to find some resorts is [this website](http://www.bergfex.at/oesterreich/), that maps a lot of them to a map. You're particularly interested in those on the left side of Austria. [This site](http://www.skigebiete-test.de/skigebiete/oesterreich) is very similar, but maybe even easier to understand, since here Munich is also displayed. Some of the biggest and most popular ski resorts in Austria are:

[Ischgl](http://www.skigebiete-test.de/skigebiete/ischgl.html) (particularly to do some Après-Ski)

[Kitzbühel](http://www.skigebiete-test.de/skigebiete/kitzbuehel.html) (famous for its world cup ski race)

[Lech am Arlberg](http://www.skigebiete-test.de/skigebiete/lech-zuers-am-arlberg.html) (on the border between Vorarlberg and Tirol, it is immo the biggest ski resort around Munich)

[St. Anton am Arlberg](http://www.skigebiete-test.de/skigebiete/st-anton-am-arlberg.html) (its own ski resort, but also part of a association between various ski resorts in the Arlberg region. You can go skiing here and with the same ticket also in Lech and other resorts.)

[Sölden](http://www.skigebiete-test.de/skigebiete/soelden.html) (famous for the world cup start every winter and a lot of party going on there)

I tried almost all of them by myself, but I never checked if there is a romantic restaurant somewhere there. I would suggest you decide on a ski resort that suits you and then go to a website like [Tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.de/) to see if there is a restaurant that is ok for you.

Comment: Very nice links, thank you! I think I'll find something there :-)

Answer (score 6):

Supporting Roflcoptr's answer:

Kitzbühel was a wonderful place to go on a ski vacation, and I say this as a dyed-in-the-wool Colorado native. While I was there with a friend, and thus wasn't so much looking for a *romantic* dining option, the actual town is a fairly charming Austrian town, with lots of cozy, dark restaurants and the like that with a romantic partner could be fun.

I believe the closest actual city is Salzburg.

Comment: It is more or less in the middle between Salzburg and Innsbruck. Both cities have an airport, but if you're coming by car from Munich you will drive over/near Salzburg (which is also worth a visit btw) or Rosenheim.

Comment: Visit Mozart's House, where they make it sound like the allies bombed it on purpose.